# pip installed namespace turns into a builtin

Tags: python, namespaces, pip, uwsgi, setuptools

I'm trying to debug a complex situation in which a `*nspkg.pth` file
creates a builtin package that brakes the import in a uwsgi process.

In this case I'm still working with Python2.7.

To be sure the package is correct I started with an "almost empty" one
(whose content is shown below) and I have this strage behaviour:
if I install using `python setup.py install` everithing is ok, if I
install with `pip` the namespace seems a builtin:

```
setup(
    name='jmb.vega',
    namespace_packages=['jmb'],
    version="0.1",
    description='Test package',
    author='Alessandro Dentella',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', 'tests.*']),
    platforms='any',
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools',
    ],
)
```

While **init** in jmb is:

```
sandro@bluff:/tmp/jmb.vega$ cat jmb/__init__.py
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

What's wrong with the configuration?
Why pip makes it a builtin package?

```
   root@argo-stretch:/tmp/jmb.vega# python setup.py install
   ...
   root@argo-stretch:/tmp/jmb.vega# python -c 'import jmb; print(jmb)'
   <module 'jmb' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jmb.vega-0.1-py2.7.egg/jmb/__init__.pyc'>
```

In this case the file 'jmb.vega-0.1-nspkg.pth' is NOT created
and the egg is added to 'easy-install.pth'

When doing the installation with pip

```
   root@argo-stretch:/tmp/jmb.vega# pip install .
   Processing /tmp/jmb.vega
   Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jmb.vega==0.1)
   Installing collected packages: jmb.vega
     Running setup.py install for jmb.vega ... done
   Successfully installed jmb.vega-0.1
```

the file 'jmb.tools-0.7-py2.7-nspkg.pth' is created and the modules
seems a built-in

```
root@argo-stretch:/tmp/jmb.vega# (cd ; python -c 'import jmb; print(jmb)')
   <module 'jmb' (built-in)>
```

In the real case this is enought to break the import system of any
call to namespace 'jmb'.

the test package is

```
  jmb.vega/
   ├── jmb
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   └── vega
   │       └── __init__.py
   └── setup.py
```

sandro@bluff:/tmp/jmb.vega$ cat setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built-in. What you're seeing is normal. The module type's `__repr__` [just thinks any module object without a `__file__` is built-in](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/moduleobject.c#L197), on Python 2:

```
filename = PyModule_GetFilename((PyObject *)m);
if (filename == NULL) {
    PyErr_Clear();
    return PyString_FromFormat("<module '%s' (built-in)>", name);
}
```

Namespace packages don't have a `__file__`.

Comment: Good explanation. Just a note on the namespace package: when installed via `python setup install`, the file nspkg.pth is not created and the `__repr__` is as usual (see above)